# Update interrupted because of a resource 404

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-sources

```
Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-135 all 4.4.0-135.161                                    
  Failed to connect [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
```

My `sources.list`:

```sh
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Please try to use English here as we are not all from same language.

Comment: Failed to connect [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]

Comment: not at all @Melebius !

Comment: Yes but you have to rename Sri Lanka title with more global local keyword  to facilitate the search

Comment: @Melebius great ! you can remove this question/page

Answer (score 0):

Last line change fr.archives to archives because local french server ressource not accessible

```
#deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```